# attach HTML-Select to Inputs and store them values once user click Save button

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-select, html-input

i am dealing with got the values using plain Javascript from a list of checkboxes with a select field related to each one.

I have this **HTML** ( with three checkboxes samples )

```
  <section class="options-list">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="valueForCheckbox-01" id="cb-01" name="checkboxStatus"/>
      <label for="cb-01">Page Load Time</label>

      <select id="type-01" name="optionSelected">
        <option value="001">001</option>
        <option value="002">002</option>
        <option value="003">003</option>
        <option value="004">004</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="valueForCheckbox-02" id="cb-02" name="checkboxStatus"/>
      <label for="cb-02">DB Query</label>

      <select id="type-02" name="optionSelected">
        <option value="001">001</option>
        <option value="002">002</option>
        <option value="003">003</option>
        <option value="004">004</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="valueForCheckbox-03" id="cb-03" name="checkboxStatus"/>
      <label for="cb-03">Server Response Time</label>

      <select id="type-03" name="optionSelected">
        <option value="001">001</option>
        <option value="002">002</option>
        <option value="003">003</option>
        <option value="004">004</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="save-data" value="Save" onclick="userChoice('checkboxStatus', 'optionStatus')"/>
  </section>
```

And the following **JS** working to got the checked elements

```
var checkboxes = [];

function userChoice(checkboxName, options) {

  checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + checkboxName + '"]:checked'), cbSelected = [];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
    cbSelected.push(el.value);
    return cbSelected;
  });

  return cbSelected;
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the best way, but the piece remaining is get the options value and link to the checkbox.

And to end i'm not sure the best way to store these data, what do you suggest ?  an array of arrays ?...
[[checkboxSelected.value, option.value][checkboxSelected.value, option.value]]

...An array of object...
[{state: "checked", option: value}{state: "checked", option: value}]

..or maybe another idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select by referencing from each checkbox. Something like `cbSelected.parentNode.querySelector('select')`. I'd personally use an array of objects to store the data, but an array of arrays is possible, or an object used as a map.

```
var model1 = [
    {
        'type' : 'checkbox',
        'id' : '01',
        'checked' : true
    },
    {
        'type' : 'select',
        'id' : '01',
        'value' : 002
    }
];

var model2 = {
    '01' : {
        'checkbox' : true,
        'option' : '002'
    },
    '02' : {
        'checkbox' : false,
        'option' : 'default'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this way just can have one HTML select sibling right ? 
Can i use getElementsByClassName or ById with the parentNode instead use querySelector ?
Its just i don't know if i gonna need another <select> in the future, but in that case i just want to avoid all crash :D

Comment: You can use any selector you want, but I've gotten into the habit of using querySelector and querySelectorAll for everything, instead of getElementByXXX, since the css selectors you can use in querySelector are just way more expressive. This allowed me to remove alot of ids and classes I used to need just for the sake of efficiently selecting a node.

Comment: but with querySelector(" ") we're targeting all the tags right? as in TagName, so its dangerous i think ( probably i'm wrong )

Comment: querySelector gives you the first node that matches, querySelectorAll will give you a nodeList (array-like object) with all the matches. So querySelectorAll('.my-name') will fetch all the elements that have the class 'my-name', and hence is equivalent to getElementsByClassName('my-name') The difference is that getElementXXX gives a live htmlcollection and querySelector will accept complex css selectors like 'table.myClass td:first-child > span.otherClass' etc, so you can use the selectors you use in your css files. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Awesome ! i didn't know i could use css pseudo selectors. Thanks you so much.